# Saving values on page to server

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am creating a page that allows users to remove values from an existing list on a server and then save the new list (with values removed) to the server.

I've got the javascript function getting the right values, I'm just having trouble getting the updated list back to the server. To keep things lean I have viewstatemode="disabled".

I've seen various ways of executing javascript from the clientside.

What I'm wondering is, is it possible to have a button that calls a javascript function, gets the value it returns (or saves in a field somewhere), **all before the page goes through the OnInit, OnLoad functions?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to look like an arse and answer my own question, but in the interest of helping anyone else who stumbles upon this:

The way I tackled this problem is using the OnClientClick attribute of the asp:Button control. This allows you to call a client javascript function (obviously), but more importantly it allows you to execute code before the page lifecycle starts.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" Text="Save" onclick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="saveCurrentList();" />
```

**saveCurrentList();** is a javascript function I have in the head of my aspx page, which collects the values on the page (that have been modified by javascript, and the reason why I needed this to happen before the page posted back). I saved it in a field (using jQuery) and saving it in the field using its val(); method:

```
    function saveCurrentList() {
        var list = $("#currentList a").map(function () {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
        $("#hdnCurrentList").val(list.join(","));
    }
```

Using these techniques, I could have javascript save the values to a hidden field before the postback and then retrieve them serverside for processing.

Answer (score 1):

create hidden field like below

```
<input type="hidden" ID="hfid" />
```

set the value from javascript

```
document.getElementById("hfid").value = "value to set";
```

you can access it from server like below

```
string fromclient = Request.Form["hfid"];
```

Comment: This is not really answering the question and is just a rehash of other answers on SO about this topic. Also, it doesn't work; don't know if it's because I have ViewState disabled and you have it enabled or not....

Comment: Looking into it further, the reason why it didn't work was because you capitalized Value when it should be lowercase: value otherwise you just create a new variable in the hidden field object: [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687014/setting-hidden-input-value-in-javascript-then-accessing-it-in-codebehind/2687024#2687024)

Comment: @BrDaHa Yes, it should be `value` JavaScript is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with previous answer (i.e. storing the value in a hidden field). It also can be achieved by using cookies (persistent or non-persistent). Regards, AB